# How to Change the Content on Specific Interval using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Heading tag of HTML which contains a message.Now as per my requirement i need to change the message on every 10 Seconds.I mean i have to change the content of the heading tag on specific interval so that the message that is displaying will get change..

Here is my HTML..

```
<h1 id="dynamicMessage">Responsive Page<br/><span>Message1</span></h1>
```

Please help me to get it by the help of jquery..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for jQuery here, you can simply do that by using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) like,

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  $("#dynamicMessage").html('here is your message');
}, 10000);
```

If you want to load some random data which are loaded dynamically, then the logic must be different according to the need.

Comment: Where i can call this function ?

Comment: _There is no need for jQuery here_ - is it about `setInterval` or about `$('selector')` and `.html()`? :)

Comment: @HansalMehta You can call it anywhere, once its been called the code inside of the anonymous function would get called for every interval of time that we given.

Comment: @HansalMehta wherever you need this. For example, inside `<script>$(document).ready(function() { this code });</script>`

Comment: @Regent Yeah sure.. But .setInterval() is a part of core javascript, that's what i meant..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Ok .I do have one small query .If i need to show the changing message .How can i change the `html('here is your message');` text? I mean how can i count the show the different Message at this interval.As per my requirement i need to show the chnaging message .With This Code After the interval of 10 secs the message is getting chnaged and thats it

Comment: I gave you the solution in the chat box

Answer (score 1):

Try using following code.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $("#dynamicMessage").html("Your Text");
}, 10000);
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: You can call it like:  <script> $(function(){ //Above Function }); </script>

Comment: Ok .I do have one small query .If i need to show the changing message .How can i change the html('here is your message'); text? I mean how can i count the show the different Message at this interval.As per my requirement i need to show the chnaging message .With This Code After the interval of 10 secs the message is getting chnaged and thats it

Comment: You can use global variable for that

Comment: Could you tell me what you want to show in message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62719/discussion-between-hansal-mehta-and-amol-tate).

Comment: Yes i sent message in the chat box.