# How can i change the contents of HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Some messages to be displayed on every specific set of interval say 10 seconds.But at present i am able to show only one message .How to show rest of the messages after interval ..
Here is the Code..

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var v = "Your Text<br/>Hello";
        var v2 = "Your Text2<br/>Hello2";
        var v3 = "Your Text3<br/>Hello3";

        window.setInterval(function () {
            $("#dynamicMessage").html(v);
        }, 10000);
    </script>
```

As per my current code i am able to display the first message but how to show others like v2 ,v3 here.
Please help me..

Comment: Setup an array, insert new messages and remove the first while displaying it.

Comment: Duplicate Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270631/how-to-change-the-content-on-specific-interval-using-jquery/26270660#26270660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array with all your messages, and increase a counter inside the **setInterval** function.

You can take a look at the sample in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6c4hs91/

```
var v = {};
v[0] = "Your Text<br/>Hello";
v[1] = "Your Text2<br/>Hello2";
v[2] = "Your Text3<br/>Hello3";

var i = 0;

window.setInterval(function () {

    $("#dynamicMessage").html(v[i]);

    if (i == 2) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i = i + 1;
    }

}, 500);
```

You should control how you want the messages to appear after you get to the end of the array of messages: I have done a loop to start with the first message.

For doing the fade in/out transition just add those functions arounfd the html "write" sentence:

```
$("#dynamicMessage").fadeOut(800,'swing',$("#dynamicMessage").html(v[i]).fadeIn(100));
```

view sample in: http://jsfiddle.net/s6c4hs91/1/

For more info. on fade in take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp

Comment: I have one more query dear .Suppose i need to show the texts in Animated Faded Way .How can i dot it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : you can use array instead of three different variables and iterate through array after every 10 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var v = ["Your Text<br/>Hello","Your Text2<br/>Hello2","Your Text3<br/>Hello3"];
        var i = 0;
        window.setInterval(function () {
            $("#dynamicMessage").html(v[i]);
            i++;
            if(i==3)
              i=0;
        }, 10000);
    </script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/psj4m00p/13/)**

Comment: `if(i==v.length)` instead of `if(i==3)` would be real awesome wouldn't it? so the array can grow as big as it wants..

Comment: sorry my array declaration syntax was wrong, corrected and added demo link, please try now.

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
var messages = ["Your Text<br/>Hello","Your Text2<br/>Hello2","Your Text3<br/>Hello3"];
 var index = 0;

 window.setInterval(function () {
      index /=3;
       $("#dynamicMessage").html(messages[index]);
 }, 10000);
```